Google Sheet - Complex formula to align cartesian product in one column
Apologies about the title, I'm not sure how to formulate this.
I have this simple set of data in a google sheet:

Original
Version 1
Version 2

I'd like to have a pair of each combination, separated by a blank cell each time (and all in one column).
If there is 4 or more rows in column A, the formula should adapt to it as well.
It's going to be way easier to understand with the sample spreadsheet below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hM_NObirWaY1G9bCbZ1HMPuV9p4WX6pmBIO9ccx1gHo/edit#gid=0
Thanks in advance for the help.

You shouldn't combine Excel, Google-sheets and Spreadsheets tags, read the tag descriptions.

Sorry about this, I wanted to get maximum visibility since those kind of posts usually have very little views on those tags. Thank you for the edit. Do you have any idea about a potential formula?

This is the problem, I'm not aware of Google-Sheet functions, the gist of it is probably similar, but I'm not aware if you have EXPAND, MAP, SCAN and VSTACK. (I get that you want as many views as possible.)

Another solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(v,TOCOL(B3:B,1),i,SEQUENCE(ROWS(v)),TOCOL(SPLIT(
   TOCOL(HSTACK(TOCOL(IF(i>=TOROW(i),,v&"❅"&TOROW(v)),1),)),"❅"),2)))



Thank you so much! Works perfectly. I ran a script to compare the speed of your formula with the other answers and overall your approach seems to be the fastest option.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,tocol(B3:B,1),Λ,tocol(,1),reduce(Λ,Σ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,reduce(Λ,let(x,xmatch(c,Σ),chooserows(Σ,sequence(rows(Σ)-x,1,x+1))),lambda(f,q,if(iserr(q),Λ,vstack(f,c,q,))))))))



try:
=INDEX(TOCOL(LET(f, SPLIT(TOCOL(TOCOL(B3:B, 1)&"×"&TOROW(B3:B, 1)&"×"), "×",,), 
 QUERY(IF(INDEX(f,,1)<INDEX(f,,2), f, ), "where Col1 is not null", ))))


